# unresolved reference upon trying to get a member of anonymous class which is in a class

Tags: kotlin

```
class A{
    val b = object{
        val x = 1
    }
}

fun main() {
    val y = A()
    println(y.b.x)
}
```

I expect to see 1 but i get `Unresolved reference: x` for some reason. **Why?**

Comment: The answer, by the way, is "because `b` has type `Any` and `Any` doesn't have any fields named `x`. The anonymous subtype information is lost.

Comment: @Jorn Why is it so ? Anonymous classes are regular classes which have its own class files. Why doesn't `b` have `A$b$1` type ?

Comment: For the same reason that Java anonymous classes don't, I imagine. I'm not an expert in language or compiler design :-)

Answer (score 2):

Classes can only be a type if they have a name. That's how the language is defined.

When you declare

```
val x = "Hello"
```

it is short for

```
val x: String = "Hello"
```

When you declare

```
val x = object { }
```

it is short for

```
val x: Any = object { }
```

because the type of an anonymous class is Any, or one of the interfaces it implements. There is no phrase you could put as your anonymous class's type because you haven't defined any phrase to name it by (hence the word anonymous). You have mentioned `A$b$1`, but that is not a named type and is not valid code since it is undefined. That's just something the debugger uses to identify it.

**It's not a shortcoming. It's a feature.** Anonymous objects are one of the ways we can *encapsulate* code.

There is a special case where the compiler permits you to directly access members of an anonymous object if you are inside the same scope as where the object is declared and it is assigned either to a local variable or a private property. In your case in the original question, you are not accessing the property from inside the scope where it was declared, and it is not private. It is kind of a weird situation because the type of the property becomes hazy. You can't type its name and can't reassign it even if it's a var.

Comment: you say that `val x = object { }` is short for `val x: Any = object { }`. So if it's so, why does [this example](https://snipboard.io/hITW6P.jpg) get compiled ?

Comment: There is a special case where the compiler permits you to directly access members of an anonymous object if you are inside the same scope as where the object is declared and it is assigned either to a local variable or a **private** property. In your case in the original question, you are not accessing the property from inside the scope where it was declared, and it is not private. It is kind of a weird exception because the type of the property becomes hazy. You can't type its name and can't reassign it even if it's a `var`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `val b = object { ... }`, `b` will have a type of `Any`. So, it's effectively equivalent to writing

```kotlin
val b: Any = object { ... }
```

When you use `b`, all you know is that it's an instance of `Any`, which doesn't have any property named `x`. The same thing applies to regular classes, for example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val string: Any = "some string"
    string.length // compilation error, even though length is defined for String
}
```

What you can do instead, is to use the field while you're interacting with the anonymous class instance directly:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val xValue = object {
        val x = 1
    }.x
    println(xValue) // prints 1
}
```

If that's not particularly useful, you have to define a type to tell the compiler that it's safe to use a certain property on that instance:

```kotlin
interface MyInterface {
    val x: Int
}

fun main() {
    val instance = object : MyInterface {
        override val x = 1
    }
    println(instance.x) // prints 1
}
```

Or alternatively, you can always resort to using reflection, given that the property `x` exists at runtime:

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties

class A {
    val b = object {
        val x = 1
    }
}

fun main() {
    val anonymousClassInstance = A().b
    val property = anonymousClassInstance::class.declaredMemberProperties.find { it.name == "x" }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("...")

    val value = property.getter.call(anonymousClassInstance)
    println(value) // prints 1
}
```

Comment: if we write `val b = "hello"` the type of `b` will be `String`. Anonymous classes are the same regular classes which have its own class files. In my case the anonymous class in `A` class has `A$b$1` type. So why doesn't `b` have `A$b$1` type ?

Comment: "anonymous class" is a Java concept, it doesn't exist in the bytecode. So, to make it possible, the compiler generates a real class (with an auto-generated name) when it compiles your source code. Given that, in your source code how would you be able to use a type that the compiler has not generated yet?